# Map touch/click only firing after map tiles have rendered

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working with Leaflet JS to build a map with clustered markers on a large touch screen.

The problem we are having is that when a user clicks the marker the event does not get fired until all the tiles have loaded.

Is there a way we can still trigger the map click even though all tiles have not yet been loaded.

Comment: You are right: apparently [Leaflet is waiting the map to load all the visible tiles before firing the events](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/02db8b4e1a5c1d93282af8ad8fa052c8d02030ec/src/map/Map.js#L557)

Comment: So I just need to comment out that line. Thank you ;-)